# Calling valid? on Rails model negates manually set errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a UserBuilder class to enrich a user registration to a Devise User model. Basically in my registrations_controller, I build the resource like this:

```
  def build_resource(hash = {})
    self.resource = UserBuilder.new(hash).perform
  end
```

The idea is now to do a simple validation from this newly defined class, against an external webservice. The call to the API has been tested etcetera, so I won't bother you with the code. The thing that happens, is that a manual error is being set after an invalid call:

```
class UserBuilder
  def initialize(user_params)
    @user_params = user_params
  end

  def perform
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.errors.add(:name, :unknown) if api_call == false
    @user
  end
end
```

When I use byebug just before returning `@user` in the user builder and I call `@user.errors`, I see my assigned error. The strange thing is that when I call `@user.valid?` on the object, it returns true. Am I doing this the wrong way? I thought that the error would just persist on the object and cause the validation to fail. I'm pretty sure I've used this successfully before.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

source code of [`valid?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/070d4afacd3e9721b7e3a4634e4d026b5fa2c32c/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L334) method

```
def valid?(context = nil)
  current_context, self.validation_context = validation_context, context
  errors.clear
  run_validations!
ensure
  self.validation_context = current_context
end
```

So whenever you call `valid?` on `@user` it will clear the existing assigned errors and assigns new incase of invalid. In your case case record is valid so it will return true.

You have to add custom validation in model to return record as invalid and return the error.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :api_call
  validate :check_source

  def check_source
    errors.add(:name, :unknown) if api_call == false
  end
```

you need to assign `api_call` attribute to user while assigning new attributes.